# Expected int, but got string for redis port

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, symfony-3.3, pimcore

I have this configuration for docker:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
    environment:
      REDIS_SERVER: redis
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
```

And then in symfony I use this to configure parameters:

````yaml
# parameters.yml

    redis_port: %env(REDIS_PORT)%

And then I use the parameter to configure Picmore's cache:

```yaml
# pimcore.yml
    cache:
        pools:
            redis:
                enabled: true
                connection:
                    port: '%redis_port%'
````

But I get the error

> Invalid type for path "pimcore.cache.pools.redis.connection.port". Expected int, but got string.

The error is clear but I can't solve it, I tried different options:

```
redis_port: '%env(REDIS_PORT)%'
redis_port: '%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
```

But I get the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Symfony 3.3, but the `int` environment variable preprocessor was not added until Symfony 3.4, according to [this](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables).

I don't think you'll be able to use env vars to configure this value, since environment variables are strings by default.

Your options are to either use different `parameters` files for different environment, as things used to be done back then (which I understand can be inconvenient when using containers); or upgrade to a more recent version of Symfony.